# meta fields using elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/Changelog.rst#620-2018-07-03) for the elasticsearch-dsl python library, and one of the comments says:

> you can no longer access meta fields on a Document instance by
>   specifying ._id or similar. Instead all access needs to happen via the
>   .meta attribute.

Can I get a little more color on that?  My old (5.x) code did this

```
self._id = a_nice_natural_identiifer
```

How should that be replaced?

```
self.meta._id = a_nice_natural_identifier
or 
self.meta['_id'] = a_nice_natural_identifier
or
self.meta['id'] = a_nice_natural_identifier
```

Comment: In their tests / examples, it looks like they are using `self.meta.id`, which seems to be different than the docs? Maybe give that a go?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the correct answer is

```
self.meta['id'] = a_nice_natural_identifier
```

(Interestingly, you can also set meta properties at construction time by doing)

```
foo = SomeSubclassOfDocument(_id=a_nice_natural_identifier)
```